# Are ASP.NET WebAPI 2.2/SignalR 2.2/EntityFramework 6 realtime database notifications possible?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, signalr-hub

I have put together a small ASP.NET WebAPI application which currently receives real-time database updates utilizing the SqlDependency OnChange notification event.  I've got this working perfectly like so:

1. Javascript client performs a GET request to http://localhost:8888/api/HostEntry
2. API controller's `GetHosts()` creates a new instance of a `HostRepository` which utilizes a raw `SqlCommand` to pull all host entries from the database.  This is where the SqlDependency OnChangeEventHandler is wired up.
3. When changes are detected, the `dependency_OnChange` event fires and calls into a static method on my hub, `HostsHub.NotifyUpdate()`.
4. The `HostsHub.NotifyUpdate()` method notifies all clients that changes have been made and calls back to the client-side like so: `context.Clients.All.updateData()`.

This is all working fine and dandy, but I am curious as to how I can handle this situation with an ORM such as Entity Framework.  I understand that lifecycle we should be utilizing for the EF DB context would be "context-per-request" and that a global context is a horrible practice which most likely wouldn't work.

From every angle I look at this it seems as if both the SignalR hub as well as Web API controller need access to the same DBContext to be able to provide notifications via SqlDependency.  Please let me know if any clarification is needed.